# Getting Presence unavailable, status null of all roster

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am creating a **XMPP** Android chat client with [**asmack** library](https://github.com/flowdalic/asmack) and **Openfire** server.

I want to get the presence of all the roster from my roster list and display all online roster's, but when I check the Presence of roster it gives me unavailable for all the roster and status is null.

Below is my code how I am creating a roster and check for presence?

**setting Presence**

```
Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
presence.setStatus("I’m available");
connection.sendPacket(presence);
```

**Get Roster List and check for presence**

```
Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
Log.e("Roster Entries","Roster Entries"+entries);
//loop through
for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
    //example: get presence, type, mode, status
    Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());
    Presence.Type userType = entryPresence.getType();
    Presence.Mode mode = entryPresence.getMode();
    String status = entryPresence.getStatus();
    int state = retrieveState_mode (entryPresence.getMode()         ,entryPresence.isAvailable());
    Log.e("Presence Status","Presence status "+entryPresence.toString()+"  type  "+userType+"  mode  "+mode+"  status "+status+" state "+state);
}
```

**retriveState_mode()**

```
public static int retrieveState_mode(Presence.Mode userMode, boolean isOnline) {
    int userState = 0;
    /** 0 for offline, 1 for online, 2 for away,3 for busy*/
    if(userMode == Presence.Mode.dnd) {
        userState = 3;
    } else if (userMode == Presence.Mode.away || userMode == Presence.Mode.xa) {
        userState = 2;
    } else if (isOnline) {
        userState = 1;
    }
    return userState;
}
```

In log I get this:

```
Roster Entries﹕ Roster Entries[tusha: tusha, tushar: tushar]
Presence status unavailable  type  unavailable  mode  null  status null state 0
Presence status unavailable  type  unavailable  mode  null  status null state 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my experience before you can see status and other from Presence you need to subscribe the user.

for example:
user A want to see status and available status from user B,
in this case, user A need to subscribe user B. after that user A can see the user B Presence.

**Subscribe Code**

```
try {
            roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.manual);
            String userName = responders.getUsers().get(i).getUsername();
            roster.createEntry("userB@domain", userName, null);
            Presence pres = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribe);
            pres.setFrom("userA@domain");
            connection.sendStanza(pres);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            android.util.Log.e("tag", "unable to add contact: ", e);
        }
```